# psexec How to run exe on remote computer

Tags: psexec

I'm trying to run a program on a remote computer, but can't find the file. Whats wrong?

```
C:\temp\PSTools>psexec \\nb_IT10 -u godr\jak -p pimpam1+  c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


PsExec could not start c:\Program on nb_IT10:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Quote the path argument as it contains spaces

Comment: without spaces the same situacion. I tried c://program.exe

Comment: fixed sentence for smoother transition

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following syntax, noting that the program you are trying to run should exist on the remote computer already with this syntax.  If you only have Notepad++.exe installed locally, you'd have to use the "-c" parameter of psexec to copy that program to the server to run.

```
psexec \\nb_IT10 -u godr\jak -p pimpam1+ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

Full documentation for PSExec is available at the following link with examples [PSExec - Windows Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)